# Why does this.form.post(URI) can find one route but not the others [API Resource Routes]?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a API Resource Routes with multiple Controllers but only one ('project' => 'API\ProjectController') can be reach. I used the good URI(In the route list) for the others API Resource Routes(example: 'api/userEdit') but still get the error:

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/api/userEdit 404 (Not Found)

{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
file: "C:\Users\PC-HP\Desktop\myapp\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php"
line: 179
message: ""
trace: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]

**All my Controllers exist in Http/Controllers/API.** This is very strange.

Thanks for your help.

CreateProject.vue (Work with 'project' => 'API\ProjectController')

```
<template>
<div>

<form @submit.prevent="addProject">

    <div class="create-form" id="" style="margin-left:40%;margin-top:80px;">

        <div class="mt-4">
            <label for="usr">Project Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" v-model="form.title"  class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('title') }"  required>
            <has-error :form="form" field="title"></has-error>
        </div>  

        <div class="mt-4">
            <label for="usr">Description:</label><br>
            <textarea v-model="form.desc" name="desc" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('desc') }" required></textarea>
            <has-error :form="form" field="desc"></has-error>
        </div>      

        <div class="mt-4">
            <label for="usr">Keys words:</label><br>
            <input type="text" v-model="form.keyword" name="keyword"  class="form-control" v-on:keyup.space="addKeywords">
            <li v-for="(keyw,index) in form.keywords" :key="index">{{keyw}}<a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteKeywords(index)">x</a></li>
        </div>  

        <div class="" id="">
            <label for="usr">Category</label><br>
            <select v-model="form.category"  class="form-control">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Select a choice</option>
            <option value="2">gfdg</option>
            <option value="3">gffdg</option>
            <option value="4">fdsfd</option>
            <option value="5">gfdgfd</option>
            <option value="6">gfdgf</option>
            <option value="7">gfddfg</option>
            <option value="8">wewerw</option>
            </select>
        </div>  



        <label class="mt-4">Images</label><br>

        <div class="uploader-create-project" @dragenter="OnDragEnter" @dragleave="OnDragLeave" @dragover.prevent @drop="onDrop" :class="{ dragging: form.isDragging }">


            <div class="upload-control" v-show="form.images.length">
            <label for="file">Select a file</label>
            </div>


            <div v-show="!form.images.length">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                <p>Drag your images here</p>
                <div>OR</div>
                <div class="file-input">
                    <label for="file">Select a file</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" @change="onInputChange" multiple>
                </div>  
            </div>

            <div class="images-preview" v-show="form.images.length">
                <div class="img-wrapper" v-for="(image,index) in form.images" :key="index">
                <img :src="image" :alt="`Image Uploader ${index}`">
                    <div class="details">           
                        <span class="name" v-text="form.files[index].name" ></span>         
                    </div>  
                    <a href='#' @click.prevent="deleteImage(index)" class="delete-link">Delete</a>
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>


        <span>{{(form.sizefiles/1000000).toFixed(2)}} Mo</span> 




        <div class="mt-4">
            <label for="usr">Poste</label><br>

            <input type="text" v-model="form.task_name"  class="form-control" name="task">

            <label style="margin-left:20px;">person required</label>
                <select v-model="form.nbr_person" form="carform"  class="form-control">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                </select>

            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary"  @click="addTask">+</button>

        </div>
            <li v-for="(task,index) in form.tasks" :key="index">0/{{task.nbr_person_max}} {{task.name}} <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteTask(index)">x</a></li>

         <div class="mt-4">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.private" id="private"  name="private">
            <label for="scales">Private</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>

    </div>  

</form>




</div>
</template>









<script>

    export default{

        data(){
            return{
            form: new Form({
                title:'',
                desc:'',
                nbr_person:'',
                category:'',
                keyword:'',
                private:'',
                task_name:'',
                tasks:[],
                keywords:[],
                isDragging: false,


                dragCount:0,
                files:[],
                images:[],
                sizefiles:0,

                })
            }
        },


        methods:{




            addTask(){
            if(this.form.task_name != ''){
                if(this.form.tasks.length < 4){
                    if(this.form.nbr_person  == ''){this.form.nbr_person= 1;}
                    this.form.tasks.push({
                        name:this.form.task_name,
                        nbr_person_max:this.form.nbr_person         
                    });
                }else{ this.$toastr.e('The maximum of tasks is reach');}
            }else{
                this.$toastr.e('Please write a task in the empty field');
            }
                this.form.task_name='';
                this.form.nbr_person='';
            },
            deleteTask(index){
                this.form.tasks.splice(index,1);
            },



            addKeywords(){
                if(this.form.keyword == ' '){this.form.keyword = ''};
                if(this.form.keywords.length < 4){
                    if(this.form.keyword != ''){
                        this.form.keywords.push(this.form.keyword);
                        this.form.keyword='';
                    }else{
                        this.$toastr.e('Please write a keyword in the empty field');
                    }       
                }else{ this.$toastr.e('The maximum (4) keywords is reach'); }
            },
            deleteKeywords(index){
                this.form.keywords.splice(index,1);
            },



            addProject(){
                if(this.form.category == ''){this.form.category = 'none';}
                this.form.post('api/project');

            },









            //Upload image setting
            onInputChange(e){
                 const files = e.target.files;
                 Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
            },
            OnDragEnter(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                this.form.dragCount++;
                this.form.isDragging=true;

                return false;
            },
            OnDragLeave(e){
                e.preventDefault();


                this.form.dragCount--;
                if(this.form.dragCount <= 0)
                    this.form.isDragging=false;

            },
            onDrop(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    this.form.isDragging = false;

                    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;

                    Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));

            },
            addImage(file){

                if(!file.type.match('image.*')){
                    this.$toastr.e(`${file.name} is not an image ${file.size}`);
                    return;
                }else if( (this.form.sizefiles + file.size) <= 1000000){

                    this.form.sizefiles += file.size;

                    this.form.files.push(file);

                    const reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (e) => this.form.images.push(e.target.result);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                }else{
                    this.$toastr.e(`The maximum of space(1 Mo) have been reach  `);
                }
            },
            getFileSize(size) {
                const fSExt = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
                let i = 0;

                while(size > 900) {
                    size /= 1024;
                    i++;
                }
                return `${(Math.round(size * 100) / 100)} ${fSExt[i]}`;
             },
             deleteImage(index){

                this.form.sizefiles = this.form.sizefiles - this.form.files[index].size;
                this.form.images.splice(index,1);
                this.form.files.splice(index,1);

             },






        },







        computed:{




        }






    }

</script>
```

Profile.vue (Doesn't work with any post/get call Controller)

```
<template>
<div class="container">





<div class="profile-box" id="">




<form @submit.prevent="finishEdit">

        <div class="edit-profile mt-5 mb-5" v-show="form.active_user_edit"> 

            <h4>Edit Profile</h4>

            <div class="change-image" id="">
                <label>Profile picture</label><br>
                <input type="file" id="file"   @change="processImg">
            </div>

            <div class="change-name" id="">
                <label>Name</label><br>

                <p>Name : {{actual_user}} <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="Edit('name')">O</button></p>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-show="form.inputName" v-model="form.change_name"> 
            </div>

            <div class="change-desc" id="">

                <p>Description <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="Edit('desc')">O</button></p>

                <textarea class="form-control" v-model="form.change_desc" v-show="form.inputDesc"></textarea> 
            </div>  

            <div class="change-profession" id="">

                <p>Speciality : {{spec}} <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="Edit('spec')">O</button></p>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.change_spec" v-show="form.inputSpec"> 
            </div>  

            <div class="email" id="">

                <p>Email : {{email}} <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="Edit('email')">O</button></p>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.change_email" v-show="form.inputEmail"> 
            </div>  


            <div class="mt-4">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</button>
            </div>


        </div>  

    </form>


</div>  

</div>
</template>





<script>

//date setting
var moment = require('moment');


export default {

    props: ['username','desc','email','actual_user','sub_date','id','spec','love'],

    data(){
            return{
                form: new Form({

                    moment:moment,
                    sameUser:false,
                    id_user:0,
                    active_user_edit:'',
                    editBut:'',
                    selected_img:'',
                    showLove:'',

                    inputName:false,
                    inputEmail:false,
                    inputSpec:false,
                    inputDesc:false,

                    change_name:'',
                    change_email:'',
                    change_desc:'',
                    change_spec:'',

                })
            }
        },


    methods:{


        editProfile(){
            const check = this.form.active_user_edit;

            if(check){
                this.form.active_user_edit = false;
                console.log(this.form.active_user_edit);
            }else{
                this.form.active_user_edit = true;
                console.log(this.form.active_user_edit);
            }

        },


        processImg() {
            //this.form.selected_img =  this.$refs.file.form.selected_img[0];
            //console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        },


        Edit(part){
            if(part == 'name'){

                if(this.form.inputName == false){
                    this.form.inputName = true;
                }else{
                    this.form.inputName = false;
                }   

            }else if(part == 'desc'){

                if(this.form.inputDesc == false){
                    this.form.inputDesc = true;
                }else{
                    this.form.inputDesc = false;
                }   

            }else if(part == 'email'){

                if(this.form.inputEmail == false){
                    this.form.inputEmail = true;
                }else{
                    this.form.inputEmail = false;
                }   

            }else if(part == 'spec'){

                if(this.form.inputSpec == false){
                    this.form.inputSpec = true;
                }else{
                    this.form.inputSpec = false;
                }   

            }
        },


        finishEdit(){


            if(this.form.change_name == ''){
                this.form.change_name = this.actual_user;
            }
            if(this.form.change_email == ''){
                this.form.change_email = this.email;
            }
            if(this.form.change_spec == ''){
                this.form.change_spec = this.spec;
            }
            if(this.form.change_desc == ''){
                this.form.change_desc = 'Nothing for the moment..';
            }


            this.form.post('api/userEdit');


        },


    },








    }

</script>
```

api.php

/////

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::apiResources([
    'project' => 'API\ProjectController',
    'userEdit' => 'API\UserEditController',
    'tasks' => 'API\TaskController',
    'contact' => 'API\ContactController'

]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should know if you call api route your url should be like this:

```
localhost/api/..
```

but your url /api/ is after profile:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/api/userEdit
```

in your vuejs code replace

```
this.form.post('api/userEdit');
```

with :

```
this.form.post('/api/userEdit');
```

**/** first of url

Comment: I understand now, thanks you for your answer sir. It work.